# dynamic object (from JSON) has key called "class". Visual Studio interprets this as the keyword. How do you reference it?

Tags: c#

Assume I have a JSON item like this:

```
items:
    0:
       name: Test
       class: Something
    1:
       name: Test2
       class: Something Else
```

The JSON coming in varies, so I pass it into a `dynamic` object. My issue is when I try to get the 'class' value, Visual Studio throws errors.

For example,

```
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonAbove);

foreach (var item in response.items)
    {
        var temp = item.class; //VS fails here. the text "class" is coloured blue. VS is treating it like the keyword class.
    }
```

How can I retrieve the value stored in the 'class' key?

Thanks!

Comment: you can escape it with `item.@class`

Comment: Awesome, thankyou! I did try searching for it, but including "class" in searches just brings up explanation of what a class is!

Comment: You should also check the doc. First paragraph => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/index